# Is there a control for layering of non sibling marks in vega charts?

Tags: vega

I have a scatterplot with a brush that is inserted via code based on some behind-the-scenes javascript. I would like to have my points on top of the brush so I can interact with them when needed but I can't seem to make it happen.

`zindex` is not an option because it only works for ordering "sibling marks"?

Is there some nuanced way to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add `zindex` property to the top level marks outside of the `encode` block.

https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1341